# How do I programmatically store a file reference in a node?

Tags: nodes, 8, media

We have content type Image and it have image_data field for Image reference. So, how we could use static image path for node creation as well as for updating the image reference in the node.

Answer (score 4):

Assume, we have content type : **Image**

It have following fields in the content type.

1. **title**
2. **field_imagedata** for Image field

Now, we want to create custom node.

**Step : 1**  We need to get static image path which we would like to attach in the node. We have in "**sites\default\files\2017-01\source.png**"

So, In drupal, we could access this image uri by "**public://2017-01/source.png**".

**Step : 2** We need to create file reference in our Drupal database. Se we need to use "**File::Create**" method.

**Step : 3** After that, we could generate node using "**entity_create**".

Please look at the whole code.

```
    $uri  = file_unmanaged_copy("public://2017-01/source.png", "public://2017-01/destinatio.jpg", FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    $file = File::Create([
      'uri' => $uri,
    ]);
    $file->save();

    $new_page_values = array();
    $new_page_values['type'] = 'image';
    $new_page_values['title'] = "PARAG";
    $new_page_values['field_imageda'] = array('target_id' => $file->id());
    $new_page = entity_create('node', $new_page_values);
    $new_page->save();
```

Also, you could update the node, by using the following code.

```
    // Load existing node and attach file.
    $node = Node::load(1); 
    $node->field_imageda->setValue([
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
    ]);
    $node->save();
```

Using this code, you could create new node with the static file.